# Not able to invoke REST APIs Sharepoint 2013 onpremise

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have deployed fresh SharePoint 2013 instance on VM. I am able to create Web-Application and Site-Collection successfully. I can even access my site, create folder, file through web browser.

However, I am not able to access REST APIs for the same site and getting below error. Please have a look on below snippet:

```
GET http://xx.xx.xx.xx/_api/web/lists
```

Getting error as **"The Web application at http://xx.xx.xx.xx could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application."**

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using with host name or IP?
if you are using hostname, you should add new entry in hosts file.
Structure:

IP               Host Name

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  contoso

http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-windows

Or

You can modify alternate access mappings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings